# build.gradle file, task using << notation, intellij warns: "Cannot infer argument type"

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea, gradle

I'm new to groovy and gradle and was wondering whether someone knew why my scriplet wasn't working (edit actually it does work but the warning still appears). This section is taken out of the build.gradle script and intellij highlights this and complains that it: "Cannot infer argument types". any help would be nice :)

```
task hellofun << {
    [silly:'billy'].each { k, v ->
        println "$k=$v"
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** I  have submitted a [bug request](http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/requests/16896) informing Intellij of this problem

**EDIT:** apparently this is a [known bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-116430) I'll update this once the bug is fixed

Comment: That's odd. Your code works flawlessly for me. What version of Gradle are you using? Will the task fail, or is the problem just that intellij is complaining about it?

Comment: huh... it also works for me but intellij complains about it.

Comment: Which version of IntelliJ? Can't reproduce in IntelliJ 13. (IntelliJ 12 has very limited Gradle support.) In any case, it's just a warning, and I don't know what you mean by "my scriplet wasn't working".

Comment: it is definitely intellij 13. version IU-133.193 to be precise

Comment: I have the same issue with IU-133.471

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are willing to disable the Groovy > Assignment Issues > Incompatible type assignments inspection, the warning goes away.

Comment: ah yes, sweep the problem under carpet.

Answer (score 3):

In a highly dynamically typed language such as groovy where names and symbols are resolved in arbitrary ways It would be quite difficult to determine the validity of any statement ahead of time without running the program. even running the program would theoretically not divulge all possible permutations of input that may change the runtime validity of a statement.

I applaud intellij's attempt at this hard problem and can live with a few incorrect syntax warnings here and there.

Answer (score 2):

Untill the IntelliJ bug is fixed, there is a workaround: use doFirst instead of <<.

```
task hellofun() {
  doFirst {
    [silly:'billy'].each { k, v ->
      println "$k=$v"
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks for submitting the bug :)

Comment: This is not a workaround. 
You should avoid << since many people confuse configuration (){  with execution ()<<{

Answer (score 1):

For the workaround, you should really call was was indicated by the << (doLast)

```
 task hellofun() {
   doLast {
     [silly:'billy'].each { k, v ->
       println "$k=$v"
     }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Intelij press Double shift (search all) enter "Assignment Issues" and change Assignment Issues: Incompatible type assignments inspection to "OFF"